# Group images with border - Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to group some img's with a border. 
As you see in the picture below the BNN & CP24 are combo channels and I used div element to create that border. The only issue I have here is when I use div element it changes the size of the combo channels. Here the BNN & CP24 combo channel is slightly taller than the individual channels. I dont have any CSS attached to the div element. Code with the div element below.
[image]

```
        <div *ngIf="channel.compChannel[0].compChannelLogo.length !== 0; else noCompChannel">
          <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel.logo }}" alt="{{ channel.channel }}" width="100" height="100">
          <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel.compChannel[0].compChannelLogo }}" alt="{{ channel.compChannel[0].compChannelName }}"
            width="100" height="100">
        </div>
          <div #noCompChannel>
            <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel.logo }}" alt="{{ channel.channel }}" width="100" height="100">
          </div>
```

But when i use ng-container I get actual size but I am not able to create a border on the combo channels. code with ng-container below.
[image]

```
<ng-container *ngIf="channel.compChannel[0].compChannelLogo.length !== 0; else noCompChannel">
                  <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel.logo }}" alt="{{ channel.channel }}" width="100" height="100">
                  <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel.compChannel[0].compChannelLogo }}" alt="{{ channel.compChannel[0].compChannelName }}"
                    width="100" height="100">
                </ng-container>
                  <ng-template #noCompChannel>
                    <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel.logo }}" alt="{{ channel.channel }}" width="100" height="100">
                  </ng-template>
```

Comment: we don't understand anything without your code what you tried before

Comment: @imran, i edited my posting. thanks